# autosave large table every 10s delay

Tags: jquery, mysql, performance

I want to auto save html table which can be large(approx 1000 and more) depends on user if he wants to add more rows, so i was thinking of using setTimeout() of 10s and call the ajax function to send data to server to save it, well i'm afraid that this might freeze my UI and bring a load on my server, so i'm not asking for any code just a way to solve this problem or suggestion.

Comment: ajax calls are asynchron, so I doubt that your UI will freeze. 1000 rows should also be no problem for the server. If you want to avoid sending the whole table every time. You could add a flag to the new rows or store the new rows in a seperate list.

Comment: its like an dataEntry form so i suppose saying 1000 as more would be wrong

Comment: Is it not possible to only update what was changed? That way you could make discreet requests, maybe even [debounce](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) them if more cells are likely to be updated soon after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar not too long ago. We had tables with around 600 rows and up to 10 columns. We implemented a simple Json API. Every time the user made an edit in a field (or added a new row, created a new table etc.) we sent an AJAX request to the server with only the data of the edited row.

Thanks to event delegation we didn't have to check the whole table for changes every 10 seconds or so, but could just act upon change.

Comment: ha ha your columns are much lesser then mine i have to do it for 90 cols and 1000 or more rows but thanks for reply

Comment: That's true, but it is almost negligible as long as you only send the changed parts instead of the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a row is added or modified or deleted, flag it and send the changes only to server via AJAX every 10 seconds... That's a start.

You should consider pagination and filtering for better usability.

You could also let user choose the update frequency like 10 sec, 30 sec, etc to give better usability.

Comment: I presume some design changes would help... In fact sending batch changes and then coalescing them into single data in server is better than sending individual rows (if server can't handle loads) and also puts less load on network